# How to use java classes from visual basic 6?

Tags: java, visual-studio, com, vb6

I'm doing a small project in college and my project guide only knows visual basic 6. He is insisting on using only VB6. I'm very good in java and want to use java for the core functionality and VB6 only for the UI.

**J-Integra** may does this but it is not free, while **JCom** (sourceforge) seems to be for accessing COM objects like VB6 from Java and not the other way around. Also somewhere I red that using **javareg.exe**, one can register java classes as COM and access as below, but I couldn't find javareg.exe anywhere.

Java class:

```
public class MyTest
{ 
  public int myfunction(int value1, int value2)
  {
    return value1 + value2;
  } 
}
```

VB

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Set x = CreateObject("MyTest")
  MsgBox x.myfunction(500, 500)
End Sub
```

Anyone know how I can do as above?

Comment: *"He is insisting on using only VB6."* You might point out to him that although the VB6 **runtime** is still supported by Microsoft (through the lifecycle of Windows 7), the *development environment* is not and hasn't been for **[three solid years](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx)**. It's, frankly, whacko for him to insist you use it.

Comment: Nonsense.  VB6 is still a perfectly viable development platform.

Comment: I would agree, it is a bit insane to start a new project with VB6 at this point since the development tools are already end-of-life, and the runtime is likely to follow with future versions of windows.

Comment: I found **javareg.exe** after adding visual interdev to the installation. But it seems that, it is only for java classes that are compiled using microsoft java compiler (jvc.exe). See [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0044.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think what I am about to suggest is a bad idea, it does work (or at least has worked for me 10 yrs ago).  In my case I had to speak from a VB6 (or maybe it was VB5) to some business logic running on a Linux box.  I added a TCP port listener to the app on the Linux end and spoke to it from VB6 via TCP packets.  I basically used TCP as a bridge.

It actually worked pretty well.  So you might do the something similar.  But again, not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm far from VB6's (or VB in general) biggest fan, I would suggest that you bite the bullet and implement the whole project in VB6. Why? Because technology changes in Software over time and if you are only ever going to be fluent in one technology and haven't gone out of you comfort zone and written code in a language and a technology you're not familiar with, you will struggle to have a viable career in software development that lasts longer than a few years.

Comment: +1. Also, after the project, (if you dare to), pass this piece of advice on to your project guide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might compromise on [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org/).

Comment: That seems like a VB like syntax language for jvm. That doesn't help. I'm looking to wrap a java class in a COM object, so that I can use that COM in VB.

Comment: My thought was that your "project guide" might accept Jabaco, which could be used for your UI and could directly use Java classes you write.